# Are network masks equivalent to scope id's?

Tags: networking, ip, mask

Do scope Id's and network masks represent the same thing?
Also, are masked addresses equivalent to addresses with their scope id's. The reason I ask is because I often seen network masks indicated after a "/" after an address; scope id's are often represented as following a "%" after an address.

The reason I need to know is because I want to use RtlIpv6StringToAddressEx to convert a masked address to its binary form, but it states it takes a scope id as input, not a network mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are conceptually different thing, but are often isomorph.

Network masks identify how many addresses belongs to a same routing rule.
Scope ids identify a group of addresses taken from a same pool.

But

- because many IP subnets are organized onto Ethernet "broadcast domain" (the hots that see a same broadcast frame) and ...
- because the DHPC discovery packet send by an host with no IP address (yet) is a broadcast frame that is realyed by a router and ...
- because that router signs that packet with its own address before relaying it, to let the DHCP server to keep an address that can be sent-back and ...
- because that address to work, must be routable by that same router ...

we come to the consequence that network SUBNETS (not masks!: an address/mask pair) and scopes must at most coincide. (in fact a scope can be smaller than a subnet).

Answer (score 0):

Network masks are a way to logically separate networks.

Scope IDs tell you the reachability of nodes.

Read more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917150.aspx).